# How can I export Evolus Pencil mockups to SVG?

Tags: svg, pencil

[Evolus Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) is a powerful FOSS GUI mock-up tool. Unfortunately it doesn't support SVG export out of the box. Is there any way I can still convert my Pencil mock-ups to SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overview**

Turns out there is a way to do this using `xsltproc`, a command-line xslt-processor. The style-sheet we are going to use was developed by [Robert Kosten](https://code.google.com/u/102188467318361300957/) and released on the [issues tracker of the evolus Pencil project page](https://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/issues/detail?id=260#c1).

Quoted from the bug report:

> I would love to have this through the UI, but until then I've written
>   a small XSLT-Sheet that basically only strips everything from the
>   http://www.evolus.vn/Namespace/Pencil namespace (Mostly management
>   data not needed in an export anyway). The resulting file should work
>   fine in Firefox (where the foreignObject tag of SVG is well
>   supported), but libraries like batik (used in apache fop for example)
>   will have trouble with the XHTML, XUL or XLink in it. I intend to
>   extend the sheet to support at least a few of those elements I
>   encounter, but I won't make promises I can't keep ;-)
>
> The file attached can also be found as part of my collection of tools
>   (used to generate DocBook and then PDF for my projects):
>   https://github.com/Robert-Kosten/de.robertkosten.tools/blob/master/xsl/ep2svg.xsl
>
> It is currently under GPLv3, but I'd be willing to release it under
>   GPLv2 so no-one has to invoke "any later version" should anyone wish
>   to include it in their software ;-)

---

**Installation**

Either download the style sheet from the link above or copy and paste the following passage into a file named `ep2svg.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
This file is part of de.robertkosten.tools. de.robertkosten.tools is
free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation,
either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
de.robertkosten.tools is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General
Public License for more details. You should have received a copy of the GNU
General Public License along with de.robertkosten.tools. If not, see
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

I suggest calling this with:
xsltproc -o dir/ ep2svg.xsl input.ep

@author Robert Kosten
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:p="http://www.evolus.vn/Namespace/Pencil" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="p:Document p:Pages p:Page"/>

    <xi:include href="includes/tools.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/p:Document">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p:Pages">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p:Page">
        <exsl:document href="{p:Properties/p:Property[@name='name']}.svg" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" media-type="image/svg+xml">
            <svg version="1.1">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </svg>
        </exsl:document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p:Content">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() != 'http://www.evolus.vn/Namespace/Pencil']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[namespace-uri() != 'http://www.evolus.vn/Namespace/Pencil']" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- Void -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Save the following script as `ep2svg.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# converts evol.us Pencil mockup files to svg
# (c) 2013 Glutanimate (http://askubuntu.com/users/81372/)
# released under GNU GPL v2
# XSL source: (c) 2013 Robert Kosten (https://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/issues/detail?id=260#c1)

XSLFILE="./ep2svg.xsl"
WORKINGDIR=$(dirname "$1")


xsltproc -o "$WORKINGDIR"/ "$XSLFILE" "$@"
```

Make sure to point `XSLFILE` to the right location.

Usage:

`ep2svg.sh <mockup1.ep> <mockup2.ep> ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the mockups with Java and maven developmnet you can use the maven plugin [pencil2svg-maven-plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pencil2svg-maven-plugin/).